# issues with template binding and binding of custom component

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

I'm new to the world of WP7 and .net programming for that matter and i need help. I have a custom component that has a property that uses template binding.

```
<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Info}" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrap}"/>
```

I defined the dependency properties in the .cs file.

Now in my page.xaml i placed the custom component like so,

```
 <rounded:RoundedImageView x:Name="pivotItem1" Info="Test bind" BorderBrush="White" ImageSrc="Images/default_service.png" TextWrap="Wrap"/>
```

Which works ok, now I want the Info and TextWrap properties to be changed dynamically based on some external variables so I did this

```
 <rounded:RoundedImageView x:Name="pivotItem1" Info="{Binding sopInfo}" BorderBrush="White" ImageSrc="Images/default_service.png" TextWrap="{Binding wrap}"/>
```

where **sopInfo** and **wrap** are the external variables defined in the backing cs file of the page. But this doesn't work, the Info and TextWrap values do not change. How can i achieve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the DataContext of your Page like this:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
      DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
```

Then make sure that `sopInfo` and `wrap` are public [DependancyProperties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) of your Page class.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty sopInfoProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "sopInfo", typeof(String),
    );

public string sopInfo
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(sopInfoProperty); }
    set { SetValue(sopInfoProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! Isn't there any other way? It basically means i have to have dependency properties all over the place!!

Comment: Unfortunately, no. This his how it should be done in WPF. You could try and implement INotifyPropertyChanged instead, but you will still need to call OnPropertyChanged in every setter. WPF must have a mechanism to raise events when binding happens, that's why it needs either DependancyProperty or INotifyPropertyChanged.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx